# Ballon style for Button in WPF

Tags: wpf, button, styles

I need to style my `ToggleButton` like speech bubble. Can any body suggest me how to do this. I am new to WPF Styles honestly.

Comment: Try google around, there're tons of example. Btw, your image is not visible!

Comment: Please edit your post and show your image :-)

Comment: Thanks @Nadeem_MK, I have seen plenty of images for ToolTip style but i need same style to button. I have never seen such style for Button so.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you like the ToolTip to have such speech bubble look though it works the same with any controls.

Take a look at this:

http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.co.at/2012/03/creating-resizable-shape-controls-in.html